# Copied working ui-sref code, changed params and errors keep coming. What's wrong here?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I copied working code from my application and changed the params and errors keep coming. What's wrong? [This is the error message from AngularJS](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/error/$parse/syntax?p0=,&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=12&p3=%7Bmerchant:%20,%20invoice:%20%7D&p4=,%20invoice:%20%7D).

I've looked on StackOverflow and Google already. The AngularJS documentation is also not helping.

**Link:**

```
<a ui-sref="auth.invoice({merchant: {{ $ctrl.merchant.id }}, invoice: {{ x.id }}})" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

**StateProvider:**

```
$stateProvider.state('auth.invoice', {
        url: '/invoice/:merchant/:invoice',
        component: 'invoiceComponent'
    });
```

I want to use ui-sref with multiple params, this should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting errors because {{$ctrl.merchant.id}} and {{ x.id }} not returning any value into it and object syntax failed. Check your controller which is not attached here.

Comment: Cheers. Something weird with values being passed. Got it working now!